# mssql_rows_affected returns wrong number of rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

the code bellow, is a PHP script that activates a user's account by clicking a link.
The SQL query is executed which updates a table. The update is fine but in the end I'm displaying a message, if activation was successful or not. but `mssql_rows_affected` returns probably `0` so even the update is successful I'm getting the wrong message. Can't understand whats wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
$account = $_GET['account'];
$code = $_GET['code'];

$account = antiinjection($account);
$code = antiinjection($code);

connectdb($CONFIG['dbdbname'], $CONFIG['dbaddress'], $CONFIG['dbuser'], $CONFIG['dbpass']);
mssql_query (sprintf(UPDATE_PAY_STAT, $account, $code));
mssql_query("COMMIT");
$rowsaffected = mssql_rows_affected();
$message =  "
                <div align=center>The account {$account} has been activated! Have fun!</div>
            ";

if( $rowsaffected != 0 ){
echo "$message";
}
else
{
    $message =  "
                <div align=center>The account {$account} has not been activated due to an error. Please contact the Account Support.</div>
                ";
}

echopage('header', 'Activate');
echo($message);
echopage('footer', '');
```

Comment: Try doing your `$rowsaffected = mssql_rows_affected();` __before__ the `commit`

Comment: Alternatively, try passing a db link resource as an argument to `mssql_rows_affected()`

Comment: tried before the commit but got the same result. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because i couldn't manage to get mssql_affected_rows() work, I did it like this. I added 1 more sql query that checks if x account name has pay_stat ='1'. Thanks for your answers!

```
   $link=mssql_query (sprintf(SELECT_COUNT_PS, $account));
$row = mssql_fetch_row($link);

if( $row[0] == '1' ){
$message =  "
                <div align=center>The account {$account} has been activated! Have fun!</div>
            ";
}
else
{
    $message =  "
                <div align=center>The account {$account} has not been activated due to an error. Please contact the Account Support.</div>
                ";
}
```